# [Java,Picasso, BuildError,Android]

Tags: java, android, maven, compiler-errors, picasso

When I build it say

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/com.squareup.picasso/picasso/pom.properties
>       File1: C:\Users\Daniel\AndroidStudioProjects\StreamingFilm\app\libs\picasso-2.5.2.jar
>       File2: C:\Users\Daniel.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.picasso\picasso\2.5.2\7446d06ec8d4f7ffcc53f1da37c95f200dcb9387\picasso-2.5.2.jar`
>   What should I do to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be including Picasso both via a JAR in `libs/` and via an artifact (e.g., `com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2`). Only do one of these.